# What is the best Host provider for Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: php, hosting, apple-push-notifications

I would like to know , the best affordable Hoster for APNs

Because it requires 2195&2196 ports to be opened to work...

i checked site5 & justhost

Please let me know which one is the best to go with it

Thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like any VPS would work.

See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/808/who-is-your-favorite-vps-provider/, [Finding the right VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109631/finding-the-right-vps), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226951/favorite-vps-host, [VPS hosting and root access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563163/vps-hosting-and-root-access)

Comment: iam using site5, its good enough to handle APNS, it will give access to cron job for every 15 mins